# Get post id by attachment id?

Tags: posts, attachments

I have attachment id, but can't find way to get post id by this attachment id. I can loop all posts and find it, but maybe exists easy way get it. Does anyone know a similar function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`get_post_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) can give you the ID of the object an attachment is associated with:

```
$attachment_id = 42;
$parent = get_post_ancestors( $attachment_id );
echo $parent[0]; // $parent will be an array
```